# mysql query with some calculation from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables ,

```
**Member table**

mid | parentid | name
1           1      a
2           1      x
3           1      c
4           2      d
5           3      e
6           3      f
7           4      g
```

and

```
**contact table** 

cid   |    mid
1           1    
2           1     
3           3      
4           2      
5           3      
6           4      
7           4
```

I need a query to show a list of members and be sorted from the highest number of people they are parent to them on the 2 tables so the answer will be

```
id | name  |rank
1      a     5
3      c     4
4      d     3
2      b     2
5      f     0
6      g     0
7      h     0
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far - this is no "give me the code" community...

Comment: Your examples can't be right.There is no name h in your member table (and there is in your result) and there is a x in your member table without result. And what does you contact table do exactly? In your result-description you don't mention any "contacts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY` is the way to solve this. This might work, but I have not tested it.

```
SELECT
    member.mid AS id,
    member.name AS name,
    COUNT(counter.x) AS rank
FROM 
    member,
    (
        SELECT parentid AS x FROM member
        UNION ALL
        SELECT mid AS x FROM contact
    ) AS counter
WHERE
    member.mid = counter.x
GROUP BY counter.x
SORT BY counter.x DESC
```

Comment: what if we need to show the members how had zero rank ?

Comment: You can do it using a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).